# How do I use AFOAuth2Manager to get application credentials for the Twitter REST API

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, twitter-oauth, twitter-rest-api

I'm trying to access a single part of the Twitter API, without logging in a user account (application-only authentication is what I want), so I don't want to add some framework just to perform this one operation. I'm trying to do it with AFNetworking instead based on the description here: https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/reference/post/oauth2/token .

Here's what I have so far

```
AFOAuth2Manager *authManager = [[AFOAuth2Manager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/"]
                                                               clientID:TwitterAPIKey
                                                                 secret:TwitterSecret];
[authManager authenticateUsingOAuthWithURLString:@"oauth2/token"
                                      parameters:nil
                                         success:^(AFOAuthCredential *credential) {
                                           AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:TwitterBaseURL]];
                                           [manager.requestSerializer setAuthorizationHeaderFieldWithCredential:credential];
                                           //do some stuff
                                         }
                                         failure:^(NSError *error) {
                                           //handle the failure, where I'm currently ending up
                                         }];
```

When run, this fails to authenticate with a 403 forbidden error. Can anyone explain to me where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 4):

It was a stupid mistake -- I didn't realize that I needed a parameter. passing `@{@"grant_type": @"client_credentials"}` for parameters instead of `nil` fixed this issue.

Comment: Thank you for posting your answer.  This is what makes SO great.